# How do I put my unsorted list to the bottom of a predefined (a px *b px) box?

Tags: html, css

With my current code, the ul is put all the way to the bottom of the page, past my predefined box.

I tried using position:fixed and bottom:0

```css
.box {
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

```css
.box ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

.box li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.box a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
}
```

I expected the ul to go to the bottom of the box and then I could use padding or margin to slightly put it up so it's not resting completely at the bottom of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the entire viewport, which is why you are seeing it at the bottom of the page, where `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to its parent element. You may have to add `position: relative;` to `.box`, then change `fixed` to `absolute` in `.box ul`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!
Also, if I want to now center the ul and put a gap between all the list items, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Flexbox is your best bet to achieve that:
`.box {
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;justify-content: center;
}`

`.box ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}`

`.box li {
    display: inline-block;
}`

`.box a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
}`

Comment: So I added the flexbox but using 100% width made the "buttons" go too far to the right. Giving it a 90% width made it relatively centered by the eye but it's not 100%. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, use absolute. try this

```
.box {
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
}

.box ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.box li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.box a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
}
```